# Как работает @JoinColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8

Видел много примеров, но все еще не совсем понимаю, в каких случаях пишется эта аннотация. Вот допустим у нас сущности `User` и `Book`, между ними отношения `OneToMany` в `User` и `ManyToOne` в `Books` соответственно. Так вот, я прочитал, что `@JoinColumn` использует та сущность, которая в этих отношениях является "главной", а та сущность, которая не несет ответственности, помечается как `mappedBy`.

Допустим у нас есть два класс-сущности:

```
@Entity
@Table (name="users")
public class Person
{
    private String name;

    @OneToOne (optional=false, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn (name="passport_id")
    private Passport passport;
}

@Entity
@Table (name="passports")
public class Passport
{
    private String series;
    private String number;

    @OneToOne (optional=false, mappedBy="passport")
    private Person owner;
}
```

Этот пример я увидел в одной статье. Какой из этих классов является главным, по отношению к другому? И что вообще значит главный?

Comment: Аннотация `@JoinColumn` нужна только тогда, когда вас не устраивает автоматически используемое имя колонки, по которому делается объединение.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev то есть вы хотите сказать, что она нужна только для того, чтобы в ее поле name ввести то название, которое хочу для той колонки, которая содержит внешние ключи? Или я неправильно понял

Comment: Да. Обычно такая надобность появляется, когда сущности городятся поверх легайси-базы.